# Error al intentar mostrar datos de la base de datos con PHP con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando mostrar datos que tengo en la base de datos mysql con phpmyadmin pero me salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si hay algún error al llamar a la clase o la estoy llamando mal, ya que no me reconoce la variable de registros que le indico en el `foreach` (la cual está dentro de otra clase)

Código de la clase:

```
    public function visualizar() {
 
        require 'config.php';
        //realiza una consulta a la tabla animal
$registros = $base->query("SELECT  nombre, edad, sexo, tamanyo, esterilizado,"
        . " id_protectora, raza FROM animal")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //almacenamos un array de obj


    
    }
}
```

```
    require ('index.php');
    $vista = new Animales();
    $mostrar = $vista->visualizar();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Saving Paws</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cssanimales.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="primera">Nombre</td>
            <td class="primera">Edad</td>
            <td class="primera">Sexo</td>
            <td class="primera">Tamaño</td>
            <td class="primera">Esterilizado</td> 
            <td class="primera">Protectora</td> 
            <td class="primera">Raza</td> 
        </tr>
  
<tbody>
       <tr>
       // foreach
   <?php foreach ($mostrar as $resultado){ ?>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['nombre']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['edad']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['sexo']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['tamanyo']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['esterilizado']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['id_protectora']; ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $mostrar['raza']; ?> </td>
 
      </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</tbody>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Después de definir los $registros, debes devolverlos con `return $registros;` al final de la función **visualizar**.  Y en tu otro código cambia `$vista->visualizar();` por `$registros = $vista->visualizar();` para que esa variable $registros asignada a $vista->visualizar consiga los $registros de la función.  Tu problema es que piensas que las variables de las funciones de las clases son globales, y no lo son a menos que se definan como tales, pero eso es otra explicación... mejor haz lo que comento y ya nos cuentas.

Comment: Intenta por favor poner el HTML en modo texto para una mejor ayuda con las triples comillas              Ejemplo  :                                                                                                              ```                                                                                                                                   TuCodigo                                                                                                                                     ```

Comment: ¿Estás usando [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) o [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)?. En cualquier caso están mal utilizadas. Ver la documentación. ¿Sabes lo que devuelve `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` y [cómo tratarlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42983571/1545868)?

Comment: @JavierG.Raya acabo de actualizar todo

Comment: @aeportugal estoy usando pdo

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias, ya lo he solucionado! :)

Comment: @NereaVázquez pon la solución en la respuestas como posibles futuros errores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soluciones:
Después de definir los $registros, debes devolverlos con return $registros; al final de la función visualizar. Y en tu otro código cambia `$vista->visualizar();` por `$registros = $vista->visualizar();` para que esa variable $registros asignada a $vista->visualizar consiga los $registros de la función.

Tu problema es que piensas que las variables de las funciones de las clases son globales, y no lo son a menos que se definan como tales, pero eso es otra explicación... mejor haz lo que comento y ya nos cuentas.

- Usar correctamente PDO en el archivo html para mostrar los registros de la bd.
  forma correcta de expresarlo con pdo:

```php
<?php 
foreach ($mostrar as $resultado){ ?>
   <td> <?php echo $resultado->nombre; ?> </td>
}
```

Comment: mucho mejor te has ganado mi voto :)

Comment: no te olvides de cuando pase 48 horas de marcar tu respuesta como la correcta